I'm trying to build a port scanner but the provided function keeps giving NONE value, this section is supposed to take port/s from the user
import re
import termcolor


port_regex = re.compile(r'^\d{1,5}$|^\d{1,5}-\d{1,5}|\d{1,5}(,\d{1,5})*$')
def port_is_valid(port):
       result = bool(port_regex.match(port))
       print(result)


def get_port():
    str_ports = input(termcolor.colored("Specify The Ports: ", "light_cyan"))
    print(str_ports)

    if port_is_valid(str_ports):
        if "," in str_ports:
            nm_ports = str_ports.split(",")
            int_ports = [int(port) for port in nm_ports]
            print("sp")
            return int_ports
        elif "-" in str_ports:
            f_ports = []
            nm_ports = str_ports.split("-")
            if int(nm_ports[0]) > int(nm_ports[1]):
                print(termcolor.colored("order of ports range is not correct !!!", "red"))
                get_port()
                return None
            else:
                for port in range(int(nm_ports[0]), int(nm_ports[1]) + 1):
                    f_ports.append(port)
                print("rg")
                return f_ports
        else:
            try:
                int_port = int(str_ports)
                return int_port  
            except ValueError:
                print("Invalid port format")
                return None  # Return None for invalid single port


port_t = get_port()

I tried debugging the code to see why the function keeps giving none value but the pointer jumps from the port_is_valid function to the end of the provided code

Actually, it doesn't depend on input.  port_is_valid ALWAYS returns None, because you have no return statement.

port_is_valid always returns None (implicitly) since you don't have a return statement. So no matter whether the port is actually valid, it always returns None, which is interpreted as False. So if port_is_valid(...) is never entered, and there's nothing left of your function

You need to return something from this function:
def port_is_valid(port):
       result = bool(port_regex.match(port))
       print(result)

maybe
def port_is_valid(port):
       result = bool(port_regex.match(port))
       print(result)
       return result

If you don't return, None will be returned and its casts to False in your if.

thank you I just checked and turned out that you're right
